Certbot get certificate failed for elastic beanstalk
I’m having trouble with our Elastic Beanstalk setup. After uploading a new version of our API, the deployment failed and rolled back, but the old version still works fine.
I cloned the Elastic Beanstalk environment to try update environment, but now the API isn’t working after the clone, even though it should have the same configuration. Reverting to the original environment didn’t fix the issue either.
I’m new to AWS and need help figuring out what might be wrong and how to fix it, especially with .ebextensions and SSL errors. Any step-by-step advice would be greatly appreciated.
here cfn-init.log for Command 50_getcert
2024-09-03 06:53:21,178 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2024-09-03 06:53:21,182 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2024-09-03 06:53:21,186 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_api
2024-09-03 06:53:25,287 [INFO] Command 10_downloadepel succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:25,571 [INFO] Command 20_installepel succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:26,999 [INFO] Command 30_enableepl succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:42,080 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2024-09-03 06:53:42,091 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2024-09-03 06:53:42,093 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2024-09-03 06:53:42,096 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_api
2024-09-03 06:53:46,033 [INFO] Command 10_downloadepel succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:46,176 [INFO] Command 20_installepel succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:46,825 [INFO] Command 30_enableepl succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:55,423 [INFO] Command 40_installcertbot succeeded
2024-09-03 06:54:00,545 [INFO] Command 40_installcertbot succeeded
2024-09-03 06:54:00,847 [ERROR] Command 50_getcert (sudo certbot certonly --debug --non-interactive --email no-reply@myemail.com --agree-tos --standalone --domains mydomain.com --keep-until-expiring --pre-hook "sudo service nginx stop" --post-hook "sudo service nginx start") failed
2024-09-03 06:54:00,847 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_api: Command 50_getcert failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 278, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 50_getcert failed
2024-09-03 06:54:00,851 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2024-09-03 06:54:00,851 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 50_getcert failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 181, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets, strict_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata, strict_mode).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 567, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 278, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 50_getcert failed

error.log
2024/09/03 06:54:12 [error] 9745#9745: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/server" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /server HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:13 [error] 9745#9745: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/.vscode/sftp.json" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /.vscode/sftp.json HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:13 [error] 9745#9745: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/about" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /about HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:13 [error] 9745#9745: *8 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/debug/default/view" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /debug/default/view?panel=config HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:14 [error] 9745#9745: *9 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/v2/_catalog" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /v2/_catalog HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:14 [error] 9745#9745: *10 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/ecp/Current/exporttool/microsoft.exchange.ediscovery.exporttool.application" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /ecp/Current/exporttool/microsoft.exchange.ediscovery.exporttool.application HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:14 [error] 9745#9745: *11 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/server-status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:15 [error] 9745#9745: *12 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/login.action" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /login.action HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:15 [error] 9745#9745: *13 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/_all_dbs" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /_all_dbs HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:15 [error] 9745#9745: *14 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/.DS_Store" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /.DS_Store HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:16 [error] 9745#9745: *15 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/.env" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:16 [error] 9745#9745: *16 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/.git/config" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:16 [error] 9745#9745: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/s/534313e25353e2933313e28313//;/META-INF/maven/com.atlassian.jira/jira-webapp-dist/pom.properties" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /s/534313e25353e2933313e28313//;/META-INF/maven/com.atlassian.jira/jira-webapp-dist/pom.properties HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:16 [error] 9745#9745: *18 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/config.json" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /config.json HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"
2024/09/03 06:54:17 [error] 9745#9745: *19 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/telescope/requests" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.226.78.121, server: _, request: "GET /telescope/requests HTTP/1.1", host: "api.astagatra.com"

access log
207.241.236.83 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; archive.org_bot +http://archive.org/details/archive.org_bot) Zeno/5aed272 warc/v0.8.43" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:12 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\x04\x01\x00\x01\x00\x03\x03r\xEFK.\xF6\x14\xF4(R\xA0\xED\xF4\xD2\x8B\xCF4\x00\xE2\xA3\xF5\xDF\xA0\x91\xA0%\xAD\xA9'\xAC\xB1\xEC& LD\xE5,3\xEA\xF9jw!\xBF\x04\x08M\x9E\x16\x81\x11hb\xE2\xEFG\x5C\x99\xE08\x97\xD2" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "-" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; HTC One M9 Build/MRA17051) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.3111.98 Mobile Safari/537.3" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:12 +0000] "GET /server HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:13 +0000] "GET /.vscode/sftp.json HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:13 +0000] "GET /about HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:13 +0000] "GET /debug/default/view?panel=config HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:14 +0000] "GET /v2/_catalog HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:14 +0000] "GET /ecp/Current/exporttool/microsoft.exchange.ediscovery.exporttool.application HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:14 +0000] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:15 +0000] "GET /login.action HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:15 +0000] "GET /_all_dbs HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (l9scan/2.0.534313e25353e2933313e28313; +https://leakix.net)" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:15 +0000] "GET /.DS_Store HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:16 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:16 +0000] "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:16 +0000] "GET /s/534313e25353e2933313e28313/_/;/META-INF/maven/com.atlassian.jira/jira-webapp-dist/pom.properties HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:16 +0000] "GET /config.json HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:17 +0000] "GET /telescope/requests HTTP/1.1" 404 3665 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
64.226.78.121 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:17 +0000] "GET /?rest_route=/wp/v2/users/ HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
88.99.26.177 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:54:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 14) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.5993.80 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
205.169.39.0 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:55:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.5938.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
34.72.176.129 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:55:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36" "-"
205.169.39.134 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:55:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36" "-"
205.169.39.134 - - [03/Sep/2024:06:55:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36" "-"

letsencrypt.log
2024-09-03 06:54:01,554:ERROR:certbot.compat.misc:Error output from post-hook command sudo:
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start nginx.service

ssl config .ebextension
container_commands:
   10_downloadepel: 
    command: "sudo wget -r --no-parent -A 'epel-release-*.rpm' https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/"
  20_installepel: 
    command: "sudo rpm -Uvh archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-*.rpm --force"
  30_enableepl: 
    command: "sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel*"
  40_installcertbot: 
    command: "sudo yum install -y certbot"
  50_getcert: 
command: "sudo certbot certonly --debug --non-interactive --email no-reply@mail.astagatra.com --agree-tos --standalone --domains api.astagatra.com --keep-until-expiring --pre-hook \"sudo service nginx stop\" --post-hook \"sudo service nginx start\""
60_link: 
    command: "ln -sf /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.astagatra.com /etc/letsencrypt/live/ebcert"

https custom confiq nginx
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 256;
}

# HTTP server
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
    include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/he*.conf;
    client_max_body_size    25M;
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen       443 default ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    error_page 497 https://$host$request_uri;
    client_max_body_size    25M;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
    
    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/ebcert/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/ebcert/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location ~ ^/(lib/|img/) {
        root /var/app/current/public;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection      "Upgrade";
    }
}

nginx config
#Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    32137;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }
}


It seems that Nginx is up on port 80 but it doesn't serve any thing other than index.html and error.html. can you verify Nginx configuration ? Did you chek also access.log ?

@MedAgou i add it above please check it

is your domain api.astagatra.com is correctly pointed to your EB environment

@MedAgou yes added to route 53
